# Hydration error in Next js because of mismatch between UI and server markup

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration

Background - I am not sure what I did to cause this as I have come back to this after 6 months off, but now there's a hydration error:

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

[link to my project on github](https://github.com/YazminLeigh/duncan-campbell)

I have attempted to debug by commenting out components sequentially to search for the origin of the error (both their own files, and where they are used elsewhere) - nothing gets rid of the hydration error.  I think I understand that if you find the origin you can then use a useEffect but alas not found.

After this, and after checking my JSX is all nice (pretty sure it is but struggling to find a 'perfect JSX checklist' ... what else can I do please?

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Three screenshots...
https://photos.app.goo.gl/io5aRg79AayqECBj6
Thanks

Comment: The link to your GH repo gives 404, can you recheck it?